# Parsing complex nested JSON data with Gson

Tags: java, json, object, nested, gson

I'm using Gson to parse a JSON string. I want to convert this to an object using a container class and embedded static classes. To some extent this has been possible, but I want to treat the content of `stuff1` and `stuff2` as arrays, for example, `stuff1` is an array containing `other_stuff1` and `other_stuff2`. This is so I can reference the object in a fashion like these: `object.integer`,  `object.stuff1.get("other_stuff1").name`, or `object.stuff2.get("other_stuff3").more`. (for the last one, I could be interested in looping over `more` to get each item.

For example, in PHP, I would use this:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    $object = json_decode(file_get_contents("THE JSON FILENAME"));
    foreach($object->stuff1 as $name=>$data) {
        echo $name . ":\n"; // other_stuff1 or other_stuff2
        echo $unlockable->description . "\n\n"; // Got lots of stuff or Got even more stuff.
    }
?>
```

I want to be able to reference in a similar way, loading the JSON to an object to be used on the fly.

It is crucial that, while some degree of change can be made to the JSON, that the names of the elements remain and be referable and retrievable.

I've included JSON, very similar to the one I'm using, below.

```
{
    "integer":"12345",
    "stuff1":{
        "other_stuff1":{
            "name":"a_name",
            "description":"Got lots of stuff.",
            "boolean":false
        },
        "other_stuff2":{
            "name":"another_name",
            "description":"Got even more stuff",
            "boolean":true
        }
    },
    "stuff2":{
        "other_stuff3":{
            "name":"a_name",
            "description":"Got even more stuff",
            "boolean":false,
            "more":{
                "option1":{
                    "name":"hello"
                },
                "option2":{
                    "name":"goodbye"
                }
            }
        },
    }
}
```

I've gone through a number of reference guides and tutorials, and I can't find a way to interpret this the way I'm trying to.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me a pointer. I can't find any tutorials that take into account that a) I want multiple objects in an array-style list, referable by the IDs (like with `other_stuff1` and `other_stuff2`), and b) I want to also be able to loop over the items without providing the IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define a Java class with fields named after the keys you need.  You can use [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)s (not arrays) to get the `.get("key")` behavior you describe.  For example:

```
class Container {
  private final int integer;
  private final HashMap<String, Stuff> stuff1;
  private final HashMap<String, Stuff> stuff2;
}

class Stuff {
  private final String name;
  private final String description;
  @SerializedName("boolean") private final boolean bool;
  private final HashMap<String, Option> more;
}

class Option {
  private final String name;
}
```

For the `"boolean"` field you need need to [use a different variable name](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support) since `boolean` is a reserved keyword.

You can then do:

```
Container c = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Container.class);
for(Stuff s : c.getStuff1().values()) {
  System.out.println(s.getName());
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be sufficient to declare the fields in Container as `Map` instead of `HashMap`?

Comment: @ralfstx A quick test showed that if you specify `Map` Gson builds a [`com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap.java).  There's also a [`LinkedHashTreeMap`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/LinkedHashTreeMap.java) that might be returned sometimes.  It's probably best to be explicit about the type you want (e.g. `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, etc.) but Gson will use a reasonable default if you just specify `Map` as the desired type.

Comment: These map implementations maintain the original order of elements when iterating, which may be desired. `HashMap` is a popular implementation of the `Map` interface, but for users of the type `Container`, this implementation is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at, but OP should use what works for them. Using `Map` leaves the implementation up to Gson, which could be undesirable. Being explicit with your types is generally a good idea.

Comment: That's absolutely perfect. At this point it seems that staying with HashMap is the way to go, as it's the easiest for me to work with, but I can safely say I've been able to work with your code and turn it into exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!